# Using transform and color properties in CSS animation

Tags: javascript, css, animation, sass, css-animations

I am making a project in which there is a text(which is "happy birthday to you") and a heart. At starting, the heart drops and hit the first word, then the second, and so on. When the heart hit the text, it should turn yellow. And when the heart hit the last word, after 1 or 2 seconds the text fades and reappears with the previous color.
I have done with the transform property but messed up with the colors. Please suggest me some solutions.

```
.main .text{
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: cursive;
    color: white;
    animation: opacity-control 3.5s infinite;
    
}
.main .text span{
    display: inline-block;
    animation: text-jump 3.5s ease-in-out infinite, color-change 3.5s infinite;

    
}
.main .text span:nth-child(1){
    animation-delay: 0.25s;
}
.main .text span:nth-child(2){
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
    
.main .text span:nth-child(3){
    animation-delay: 0.75s;

}
.main .text span:nth-child(4){
    animation-delay: 1s;

}
.main .text span:nth-child(5){
    animation-delay: 1.25s;
}

@keyframes text-jump{
    0%{
        transform: translateY(0);
        color: yellow;
        
    }
    10%{
        transform: translateY(20px);
        color: yellow;
        
    }
    15%{
        transform: translateY(0);
        color: yellow;
    }
    100%{
        color: yellow;
    }
}

@keyframes opacity-control{
    0%{
        opacity: 1;
        
    }
    80%{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100%{
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes color-change{
    0%{
      
    }
    40%{
        color: yellow;
    }
    95%{
        color: yellow;
    }
    100%{
        color: white;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide the html code?

Comment: ```<body>
 <div class="main">
  <div class="text">
   <span>happy</span>
   <span>birth</span><span>day</span>
   <span>to</span>
   <span>you</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need 2 separate animations to change the text color and make it 'jump'.

Combine both of them, remove the 100% step (not needed), and change the 15% step so that it changes the text back to white after it animates.

```
@keyframes color-jump {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    color: yellow;
  }
  10% {
    transform: translateY(20px);
    color: yellow;
  }
  15% {
    transform: translateY(0);
    color: white;
  }
}
```

Change this to only use the one new animation:

```
.main .text span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation: color-jump 3.5s ease-in-out infinite;
}
```